# Mails are not going in US server?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I deployed my client and server war files in US server.At the time of sending mails I am getting an error like,

This is My LogMessage Error:

```
 23:05:29,955 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtqm
 23:05:29,982 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14 jQ5DP9vIEim-h6P_m8i8Mi5EL55j74Hl1gP-RHP8IRi2xpG5uHG9om7uShHlDFOEIZGI6i
 23:05:30,000 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14 3DcMM9uohcpo65evt_KbVhylTUsIInbaG5x8J0BgOF69th8BEy7FsbSWdQfnrmwHqoukcw
 23:05:30,016 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14 5_bfCGixiuHZvIVTc6Ar3Sk3gkylpDUgiPCHIX45qfR7NrI2wmiRyYMolIzhvPDBR_6gde
 23:05:30,027 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14 XJYBJhcAryeMPgJR9sOZJ0gqp1k4> Please log in via your web browser and
 23:05:30,031 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14 then try again.
 23:05:30,032 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
 23:05:30,034 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 qr8sm3589606pbb.47 - gsmtp
 23:05:30,037 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71) 
 23:05:30,038 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
 23:05:30,041 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
 23:05:30,044 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
 23:05:30,046 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
 23:05:30,048 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
 23:05:30,050 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at org.jboss.tools.thanqdoctor.util.JavaMail.sendMessageForSignup(JavaMail.java:200)
 23:05:30,053 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at org.jboss.tools.thanqdoctor.util.JavaMail.sendEmailForProfileActivation(JavaMail.java:328)
 23:05:30,056 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at org.jboss.tools.thanqdoctor.util.JavaMail.run(JavaMail.java:104)
 23:05:30,058 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-71)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

This is My Source Sent Mail got Message for rejection of my destination Mail:

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 root@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain gmail.com by gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.    [2607:f8b0:400e:c01::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.         Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596    dg1si10237974pad.228 - gsmtp
```

These are the Methods I am Using in My JavaMail:

```
 public static void setMailServerProperties() {
    Properties emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
}

public static MimeMessage sendEmailMessageForSignup(String to,String subject, String body) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {
    String[] toEmails = { to };

    MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    /**
     * Set the mail recipients
     * */
    for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
    }
    emailMessage.setSubject(subject);

    emailMessage.setContent(body, "text/html");  //for html email
    // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
    return emailMessage;
}

public static void sendMessageForSignup(String from, String password,String to, String sub, String body) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, from, password);
    MimeMessage emailMessage = sendEmailMessageForSignup(to,sub,body);

    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    LogMsg.info("Email sent successfully.");
}
```

What is the Difference for sending mails for US and INDIA.
Any Body Can Help Me.

Thanks in Advance,

MadanMohan

Comment: have you tried to authenticate when trying to send the email? can you post the code you used to send the email here?

Comment: where i can post code in the comment?

Comment: you edit the question and add the following information there.

Comment: Thanks for your response give me 2 minutes i will post my code.

Comment: "Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 " did not help you?

Comment: everything seems fine. Could you make sure that the user name and password are correct. And, you're not using two step authentication? And then, check the recipient's email address is correct or not (no trailing spaces, etc)

Comment: Actually i am using one source mail with that source mail i deployed the war file in us server system.In that time i am getting problem.

Comment: with same source mail i deployed in india system it is working.

Comment: I have a bit confusion from where i need to start to resolve this issue.Could you please give me any guidence brother.

Comment: I believe the response is quite clear. "The email account (root@gmail.com) that you tried to reach does not exist.". Why not try sending from gmail or yahoo to the recipient email address and see if that works.

Comment: Gmail is suspicious that it's really you logging in from the US server instead of the India server so it wants you to do something additional to prove that it's really you and not someone who has stolen your account and trying to use it to send spam.  If none of the tips on the Gmail help page are working for you, you're going to have to contact Google for help.